# Best practice to merge specific VirtualBox 4.2 snapshot *.sav file with *.vdi file

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, filesystems

I've copied my virtual machines folder completely to a new computers same folder place. Installed VirtualBox, but I can't see any Machine registered in VirtualBox explorer, and bad as it is, I've forgot to merge my snapshot (for one virtual machine) before file transfer.

All files under the "VirutalBox VM's" are untouched (last save state) and contains all the *.sav and  *.vdi files needed, at least I do expect so.

What's best the practice to merge a specific snapshot *.sav with a *.vdi file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merging a `.sav` with a `.vdi` is not a good pratice, you should export first your VM(s) as `.ova` then transfert between computers cause no more problems than network cards and shared folders.

Anyway for the VM you are trying to restore, try :

- find the file `VirtualBox.xml`
- find the node `<MachineRegistry>`
- copy a `<MachineEntry/>` line

then edit this line :

- the "`uuid`" can be find in VM folder, file `vmName.vbox`. ( on top, node  `<Machine>` ) ( example :  `uuid="{c95c504b-24fd-4b9e-867d-554be9fb9c16}"` )
- the "`src`" is the absolute path to your `vmName.vbox` file.

example of `<machineEntry>` in `VirtualBox.xml` :

```
<MachineEntry uuid="{b38a33a0-9aa9-408b-89b0-df8a121357b5}" src="C:\Users\tim\VirtualBox VMs\debian\debian.vbox"/>
```